# How do I upload large files to AWS S3 in chunks using Sinatra?

Tags: android, ruby, streaming, sinatra, aws-sdk

I have written an API in Ruby/Sinatra that connects with our Android app through http(s) endpoints. One action involves uploading (zlib-compressed) files from the Android app to our S3 bucket via the application server. Using the `aws-sdk gem`, I've been doing so using a single POST /files endpoint in which the Android client sends a zlib-compressed, base64-encoded string of the entire file in one go. This isn't a best practice on both Android and for our backend though, and I'd like to be able to read file data in chunks on a POST request and upload each part in a [multipart upload to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#create_multipart_upload-instance_method). I tried successfully implementing a Sinatra streaming GET route, but I'm unable to do the same for my purpose. How do I achieve this? And is Sinatra streaming + S3 multipart-upload the correct way to go?

Comment: Can you share your code, or a lightly-edited summary of your code so we have something to start with? Ideally both the POST that works by sending the entire file, and your attempt at a streaming solution.